# How to stop my tools strip menu items from appearing in the taskbar?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, menu, contextmenu, taskbar

I have a program which runs mainly though a NotifyIcon in the bottum right of my windows screen (XP).  Whenever I open the ContextMenuStrip that appears when the icon is right clicked, a box also appears in the task bar.  I also have nested menus inside the menu (mouse over one item leads to another menu), and each additional menu also creates a taskbar box upon appearing.  So once I am at the third or fourth nested menu, there would be 3 or 4 windows appearing in the taskbar.  After the menu disapears, so do the windows in the taskbar.

How can I stop the taskbar from displaying boxes to represent these menus?  I have done nothing in my code as far as I know to create this type of behavior.  I have searched for similar problems but have found nothing similar.  There is no "showintaskbar" property for these items as far as I can see, and no other property that I can find which would affect this.  I have investigated the owner of the contextmenustrip since I read the owner may effect these type of behaviors, but that doesnt seem to be helpful as there isn't an owner property of the contextmenustrip.

I don't know what else to search for, so I am here hoping someone can give me a clue as to what else may effect this type of behavior.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the `ContextMenuStrip.Show()` method, it will display in the taskbar as you describe. Try assigning your menu to the `NotifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip` property instead.

Comment: I tried using `MyNotifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip = MyContextMenustrip` in place of where I previously had `MyNotifyIcon.show()` (which is in a method that handles MyNotifyIcon.MouseClick), however now nothing happens when the menu usually would have shown up otherwise. Did you mean for me to do something different?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. Try assigning the `ContextMenuStrip` either in the form constructor (after `InitializeComponent()`) or in the form's load event.

Comment: assigning that in the load event instead of using a mouseclick event fixed the problem! thank you!